# Design Pattern for Multithreaded GUI Application

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, user-interface

I am working on a multithreded GUI application  GUI change depends on the data coming from another communcation thread.

1. communication thread sets data for GUI and flags for change in data.
2. Currently we are checking with the help of a timer in the main thread for flags set by the network thread and on change change GUI also.
3. But it is getting messy due to large size of project.

So if there any design pattern for these kind of problems...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

I attended a lecture by Scott L. Bain author of [Emergent Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509366) where he described using the [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) for an intermediary between gui and business logic.  In his example they were able to exchange a regular gui with (paraphrasing from memory) a natural language input for handicapped folks, without changing the business logic. Something similar may help you synchronize the data produced from your thread to your gui, while separating the  responsibility of your classes.

Answer (score 2):

How about making it event driven? The GUI layer subscribes to events from the data or communication layer and when the event is fired, knows to update itself.  In this way the GUI layer knows about the data/comms layer but not vice versa.

Btw, not sure your environment, but one must be careful updating the GUI from the thread the event is fired on.  In .NET for instance, you would need to use Control.Invoke (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to update the GUI from a non-GUI thread.